# How does SQL Server handle Varchar internally?

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I want to know how SQL Server handles `varchar` dynamic length and storage internally.

Is there beneficial to use `Varchar` if i know that i have fixed length of character is coming in column ?

I know difference between `CHAR` and `VARCHAR`, but what's best way to use in big database for database design `CHAR` or `VARCHAR` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CHAR allocates its size in row, VARCHAR stores real size of string (2 bytes) and then the real string, so overhead of varchar is +2 bytes, and overhead of CHAR is - its size minus real string length. If in varchar stored NULL value - its size in db is Zero.

See [Anatomy of the Record](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/Inside-the-Storage-Engine-Anatomy-of-a-record.aspx)

> ```
> record header
>     4 bytes long
>     two bytes of record metadata (record type)
>     two bytes pointing forward in the record to the NULL bitmap
> fixed length portion of the record, containing the columns storing data types that have fixed lengths (e.g. bigint, char(10), datetime)
> NULL bitmap
>     two bytes for count of columns in the record
>     variable number of bytes to store one bit per column in the record, regardless of whether the column is nullable or not (this is
> ```
>
> different and simpler than SQL Server 2000 which had one bit per
>   nullable column only)
>           this allows an optimization when reading columns that are NULL
>       variable-length column offset array
>           two bytes for the count of variable-length columns
>           two bytes per variable length column, giving the offset to the end of the column value
>       versioning tag
>           this is in SQL Server 2005 only and is a 14-byte structure that contains a timestamp plus a pointer into the version store in
>   tempdb